# I need to print this 20 times

Tags: python, random

So basically I have my code here which prints a random Shakespearean insult through 3 lists. To submit this code, I have to print 20 insults and I know there is a faster way than writing the final print statement 20 times. This is probably remedial but I can't remember how to do it. Here's my code thanks guys:

```
import random

list1 = ["Artless", "Bawdy", "Bootless", "Churlish", "Clouted"]
list2 = ["Base-court", "Bat-fowling", "Beetle-headed", "Clay-brained" ]
list3 = ["Apple-john", "Baggage", "Bladder", "Boar-pig", "Coxcomb"]

def nurd1():
  return (random.choice(list1))

def nurd2():
   return (random.choice(list2))

def nurd3(): 
    return (random.choice(list3))

print ("Thou" + " " + nurd1() + " " +  nurd2() + " " + nurd3() )
```

Comment: looping rings a bell ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=loop#looping-techniques

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 meh, it can be one lined

Comment: Since all those functions do is `return` a randomly-selected element from a list, and `random.choice()` already does exactly that, I think the only point to those functions is to learn how to use functions... in which case they're being poorly defined (the best definition is the one that `random.choice()` uses, with a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

words = [
["Thou"],
["Artless", "Bawdy", "Bootless", "Churlish", "Clouted"],
["Base-court", "Bat-fowling", "Beetle-headed", "Clay-brained" ],
["Apple-john", "Baggage", "Bladder", "Boar-pig", "Coxcomb"]
]

print(*(' '.join([random.choice(l) for l in words]) for r in range(20)), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice
list =[
 ["Artless", "Bawdy", "Bootless", "Churlish", "Clouted"],
 ["Base-court", "Bat-fowling", "Beetle-headed", "Clay-brained" ],
 ["Apple-john", "Baggage", "Bladder", "Boar-pig", "Coxcomb"]
]
for i in range(20):
    print '\nThou ',
    for j in range(len(list)):
        print choice(list[j]),
```

Comment: This is as basic as it gets.  I hope this helps

Comment: This shadows the built-in list type. The newline character is not necessary and I suspect OP is using Python 3.x in which print is a function instead of a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simple while loop

```
loop = 0

while(loop <= 19):
    print ("Thou" + " " + nurd1() + " " +  nurd2() + " " + nurd3() )
    loop += 1
```

tho' it'll print 20 different lines!

Comment: I would also like to know what the semicolon on the first line is doing there.

Comment: Ahaha whoops, was doing some javascript a minute ago, my bad!